# How to batch move/arrange photo files in a Lightroom catalog?

Tags: lightroom

I received a big Lightroom photo catalog with many misplaced pictures; for example half of the pictures are arranged in a 'yyyy\yyyy_MM\yyyy-MM-dd' folder structure while others are just in in 'yyyy\MM' structure.

I can use an easy Windows PowerShell script and/or Exiftool to move mis-placed pictures in proper location.

But there is a way to instruct Lightroom where to find moved files by a text file for example specification, without the need to locate every single folder/picture?

Comment: I'm new to lightroom, but my guess would be to first run `Library > Sychronize Folder`, and then select all of the files and export and with the export you can specify filename formats and you can select the folder format you want to use.  You'll then have two copies of the files and you can keep the desired format and delete the other.